# Displaying hidden divs without moving the view of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a series of divs, that serve as a demo page. Initially I have only the first div showing, with the other 2 hidden using jQuery hide() on page load. 
There is a button on each div which triggers a jQuery event of hiding the current div and showing the next div in the sequence.

I would like on the very last div (div 3), once displayed to also show the previous 2 divs, but to have div 3 still display. Meaning, the user can scroll up to see the other two divs, but without scrolling they will still be viewing div 3.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".page-2").hide();
    $(".page-3").hide();
    $(".overlay").show();

$(".overlay-button").click(function () {
    $(".overlay").hide();
    $(".page-1").fadeOut(1000);
    $(".page-2").show("slow");

});

$(".arrow-down").click(function () {
    $(".page-2").fadeOut(1000);
    $(".page-3").show();
    $(".page-2").show();
    $(".page-1").show();


});

 });
```

This code brings the view back up to the first div (".page-1").

Comment: Can you post your html code as well?  BTW, you fade-out page-2 but then immediately try and show it, which doesn't look necessary...

Comment: So you want your page to scroll to the very bottom?

Comment: I do want the fadeout effect and then to go to the final div, but then the show is necessary as I want to unhide the display of all the previous divs. 

HTML is irrelevant, as it could be anything inside the divs. The point is just to accomplish the above. @Pineda

Comment: Basically. But when I unhide the previous divs I don't want to scroll down to the third div, as I want the display to always stay there. @JonasGiuro

Comment: Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  It's not immediately obvious why you'd want to fade something in only to have it reappear immediately.  I'm surprised that the fadeOut works before the line the show page-2 gets invoked...

Comment: scrolling to the last div without an animation is basically like staying there. I'm just trying to understand if the scrollbar is involved in this thing, cause your question isn't really clear.

Comment: Yes. i just want to stay on the third div, but then the user can scroll up to the other divs if they'd like. @JonasGiuro

Comment: Add this `$('html, body').scrollTop($(document).height());` when you click on the last one.

Comment: @JonasGiuro Thanks! That works if you'd like to post as an answer.

Comment: Thanks, done below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you have all of them open the height of the page changes and the scrollbar gets left behind, to fix this you can force the scrollbar to scroll to the bottom of the page with the following snippet:

`$('html, body').scrollTop($(document).height());`